# How can I hide an ImageView on my RecyclerView for certain items based on a particular condition?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView with an ImageView being a part of the items. I want to hide the ImageView from an item in the RecyclerView if a certain condition is met. How can I do that? I am attaching the image of how I want it to look like. [image: here]

I am just defining the ImageViews in my xml layout file, so I cannot figure out how to actually remove it based on a certain condition in my android activity. I am attaching the code for the adapter class and my activity as well.

Here is the code for my adapter class

**Adapter Class**

```
public class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ReportViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ReportItem> reportlist;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private Context mContext;

    public ReportAdapter(ArrayList<ReportItem> reportlist, Context context) {
        this.reportlist = reportlist;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ReportViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView departureDate;
        public TextView flightNumber;
        public View relativelayout;

        public ReportViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener, Context context) {
            super(itemView);

            departureDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.departureDaterecyclerview);
            flightNumber =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.flightnumberrecyclerview);
            relativelayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutReports);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);


                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.report_listing_item, parent, false);
        ReportViewHolder rvh= new ReportViewHolder(v,mListener,mContext);
        return rvh;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ReportItem currentItem = reportlist.get(position);

        if(position%2==0){
            holder.relativelayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.reportlistingteal));

        } else {
            holder.relativelayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.reportlistinglightteal));
        }
        holder.departureDate.setText((currentItem.getDepartureDate()));
        holder.flightNumber.setText(currentItem.getFlightNumber());
    }
```

Here is the code for my activity file

**Activity file**

```
public class ReportListingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button uploadAllBtn;
    private EditText searchFlights;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ReportAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    ArrayList<ReportItem> reportitems = new ArrayList<>();
    private FlightViewModel flightViewModel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_listing);

        uploadAllBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploadAllReports);
        searchFlights = findViewById(R.id.searchFlightText);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        flightViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FlightViewModel.class);

        flightViewModel.getAllFlights().observe(this, new Observer<List<Flight>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Flight> flight_list) {

                if (flight_list.size() == 0) return;

                String flightno = flight_list.get(0).getFlightNumber();
                String flightdate = flight_list.get(0).getDate();

                String[] flight_details = new String[2];
                flight_details[0]= flightno;
                flight_details[1] = flightdate;

                Log.v("pp", flight_details[0]);

                for(int i = 0; i <flight_list.size();i++){
                    String flightnumber = flight_list.get(i).getFlightNumber();
                    String departuredate = flight_list.get(i).getDate();
                    

                    reportitems.add(new ReportItem(flightnumber,departuredate));

                    
                }
                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                flightViewModel.getAllFlights().removeObservers(ReportListingActivity.this);
            }
        });

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ReportListingActivity.this);
        mAdapter = new ReportAdapter(reportitems, ReportListingActivity.this);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

**Report Item**

```
public class ReportItem {

    private String departureDate;
    private String flightNumber;

    public ReportItem(String departureDate, String flightNumber) {
        this.departureDate = departureDate;
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public String getDepartureDate() {
        return departureDate;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a field in the `ReportItem` class that will tell each item if it should show or hide the ImageView in the `onBindViewHolder()` function.

Comment: I have updated the code with report item, where do I add the field there?

Comment: How do I specify it in the OnBindViewHolder method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a boolean flag to your ReportItem class for each RecyclerView item.  You will need to specify which rows show or hide this field when each item is created:

```
public class ReportItem {

    private String departureDate;
    private String flightNumber;
    private Boolean showMailIcon;

    public ReportItem(String departureDate, String flightNumber, Boolean showMailIcon) {
        this.departureDate = departureDate;
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
        this.showMailIcon = showMailIcon
    }

    public String getDepartureDate() {
        return departureDate;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public String getShowMailIcon() {
        return showMailIcon;
    }
}
```

Then update the `onBindViewHolder()` method override to use this flag to show/hide the ImageView:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ReportItem currentItem = reportlist.get(position);
  
    if (currentItem.getShowMailIcon() == true) {
        holder.mailIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.mailIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  

    //.......
}
```